# SQL Query to get Max Data

Tags: mysql

Table Info:

```
Date, Hour, Object, Data1, Data2,............, Data20,........,Data50.
```

i.e each object is having 24 hours data for each day.

Now i need to find out the result (one row) for all objects in a particular day where data20 is maximum among 24 row. Thanks in advance...

Like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `Table1`
WHERE
    `Date`='2013-12-08'
AND
    `object`='xxxx1'
AND
    `Data20` = (SELECT MAX(`Data20`) WHERE `Date` = '2013-12-08' AND `object`='xxxx1').
```

This will give max result for the object xxxx1. But I need the similar result for all objects i.e. removing condition `object`='xxxx1'. how can I do that???

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `LEFT JOIN`, only keeping rows for which there doesn't exist another row that has the same objectid, the same date and a greater value of data20;

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
  ON t1.object=t2.object
 AND t1.date = '2013-12-08'
 AND t2.date = '2013-12-08'
 AND t1.data20 < t2.data20
WHERE t2.date IS NULL;
```

...or another option would be to rewrite your old query;

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE date = '2013-12-08'
  AND DATA20=(SELECT MAX(Data20) 
              FROM Table1 t1
              WHERE date = '2013-12-08' 
                AND t1.object=table1.object)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5218/7">An SQLfiddle to test both.

If netiher gives you the performance you need, please add the `EXPLAIN` output to your question so it's possible to see actual index usage.

Comment: @ Joachim: SELECT t1.* FROM 3g_t2_24hour_data t1 LEFT JOIN 3g_t2_24hour_data t2
  ON t1.`BSC6900UCell`=t2.`BSC6900UCell`
 AND t1.`Start Time`= t2.`Start Time`
 AND t1.`VS.HSDPA.MeanChThroughput.TotalBytes (byte)`< t2.`VS.HSDPA.MeanChThroughput.TotalBytes (byte)`
WHERE t1.`Start Time`='2013-12-08' and t2.`Start Time` IS NULL

Comment: i used above query, though its not showing any error, but i have waited more than 20 mins and still no result shown, query is still running....if this query take so long time then it will not be usable for me.

Comment: @mojibul No indexes on the table? If so, which?

Comment: Indexes on BSC6900UCell(Object), Start Time (Date), Time(Hour)